# How to copy MySQL database with java jar file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jar

my MYSQL DB can find in `wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data` path called `cament_factory_db`
I copy that `cament_factory_db` folder to my netbeans project folder and changed the connection string `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cement_factory_db` to `jdbc:mysql://cement_factory_db` re-compiled it. then compiler says

> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   Communications link failure

I want to create portable jar file with MYSQL data base? How does it do ?

Comment: The last part of JDBC URL is database name, not directory name. You must create databases using mysql commands, not by filesystem operations.

Comment: I create DB using PHPmyAdmin. then bin\data folder has data base based on file system like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9tyULY_FLygWU5HNWNNQWFPOEU/edit?usp=sharing) is there any essay way to do this without typing cmd prompt ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL is not a file based database management system. It always requires a MySQL server to which the application would connect to. If you want to distribute an application which uses a database, you have two options.

1. Use a [flat file  based database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database). Then you could add the flat file to your application's distribution. Examples of such database management systems are ([SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876), [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/),[H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and [Derby](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)).
2. Use a **database server architecture**. This means that your distributed applications would not transfer the database with them, but they would connect to your database hosted somewhere over the internet. As a server database, you could use MySQL which follows this architecture.

If I get it right, the first approach would be more suitable for you.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer. if I use mysql database, I have to install it in every computer that my program run. otherwise I have to use embedded database like [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org) that can embedded with jar file